# Ways to draw n items from $3$ sets so that there are only two sets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a set $U$ containing three distinct sets $\{S_1, S_2, S_3\}$ with $|S_i| = x_i$ given, how can I draw $n$ items into a new set $U'$ so that the resulting set only consists of members of two sets?

Comment: I do not understand your question.  So, as an example... if $S_1=\{red,blue,orange,brown,\dots\}$ a set of colors and $S_2=\{chocolate,strawberry,mango,\dots\}$ a set of flavors and $S_3=\{dog,cat,monkey,\dots\}$ a set of animals... you are wanting to do what?  Count how many ways we can choose some colors and flavors but not animals or some colors and animals but not flavors or some flavors and animals but not colors?

Comment: If so, then count the number of ways to choose $n$ colors and flavors (*taking care of the possibility of all $n$ having been chosen all from the same category which you presumably want to avoid*)... that can be done in $\binom{x_1+x_2}{n}-\binom{x_1}{n}-\binom{x_2}{n}$ ways.  Add this to the number of ways you can choose $n$ colors and animals... and so on

Comment: Exactly so. For example $U'$ can contain members of $S_1$ and ($S_2$ or $S_3$) but not ($S_2$ and $S_3$). Thank you. For some reason this has eluded search and problem solving intuition.

Answer (score 1):

We can count the number of ways we can extract $n$ elements from sets $S_1$ and $S_2$, then from sets $S_1$ and $S_3$ and finally from sets $S_2$ and $S_3$.

Since all three cases are symmetric we can just count the ways to extract $n$ elements from sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ and this is $x_1 + x_2 \choose n$. When we add all cardinals we have to subtract all repeated sets, which are the sets where all elements are chosen from the same set $S_i$.

Therefore the final amount we are looking for is:

$$|U'| = {x_1 + x_2 \choose n} + {x_1 + x_3 \choose n} + {x_2 + x_3 \choose n} - {x_1 \choose n} - {x_2 \choose n} - {x_3 \choose n}$$

Comment: +1 : nice elegance.  Unclear if conclusive, re "...only consists of members of two sets".  Does this intend *at most* 2 sets, which is what you have computed, or *exactly 2 sets*.  If the latter, you would need the further adjustment of $$(-1) \times \left[\binom{x_1}{n} + \binom{x_2}{n} + \binom{x_3}{n}\right].$$